# Stumped on JOINING from two DB

Tags: mysql

I have separate two databases. One posted showing the Event planned, the second showing who of the seven members has signed up YES, as attending.

```
DB Events           Attendees
EDate 2017-01-03    Name Attend     ADate        
Title               Al    Yes    2017-01-03
Description         Bob
                    Jim   Yes    2017-01-03
                    Bob
                    Dale  Yes    2017-01-03
                    Bob
                    Jerry
```

What I would like to do is have an online record using a query of the two DB's showing who has attended which events, as well as those who have not. As shown below. Members of the group only register if they are attending so I also need to incorporate the names from the dropdown of who do not sign up and designate Yes as attending.

```
Event RECORD
EDate
Title
Description

Al    Yes
Bob   No
Jim   Yes
Bob   No
Dale  Yes
Bob   No
Jerry No
```

The EDate and ADate from the two DB are the common fields.

Any ideas . . . GREATLY appreciated.

Rik

Comment: have you got the terms table and database mixed up?

Comment: I'm not sure that you actually showed us your expected output.  Also, it is hard to read your table data.

Comment: Just do a left outer join; and in the select do a check on attend, if null make the value no